# Using node-sass watch option with grunt-sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, node-sass

How can configure grunt-sass to also watch for changes using the underlying node-sass watch option?

I understand I can achieve the same functionality with grunt-contrib-watch to watch for changes and re-run the grunt-sass task, but that will be slower since it will recompile the whole thing instead of just compiling the changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, in case this can help anyone else:

The only way I found solving this, is using the node-sass CLI through grunt. To achieve this, install the amazing [grunt-exec](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec) task and set it to run a command with the `--watch` option.

An example usage (with support for several includePath directories):

```js
exec: {
   nodeSass: {
      cmd: function() {
         // Include path option string built from the gruntConfig.cssFiles array.
         var includeFilesOption = gruntConfig.cssFiles.map(function(cssFilePath) {
            return '--include-path ' + cssFilePath;
         }).join(' ');

         return 'node-sass app/scss/style.scss app/generated/style.css' + includeFilesOption + ' --watch';
      }
   }
}
```

You will also need to install `node-sass` via npm. In that case, you can simply add the following to your `package.json` file:

```json
"scripts": {
   "install": "npm install node-sass -g"
},
```

Comment: This has other benefits btw. Using grunt-contrib-watch to run grunt-compass is not only slower but generates a new css file, while this solution only updates the css file. The result is a soft-update via the livereload option and not a full reload of the page.